# How to include results of SQL count if count=0?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have a table with grades (1-6) like so:

```
mysql> SELECT two FROM data  WHERE date >= '2018-10-23 00:00:00' AND date < '2018-10-23 23:59:59';
+------+
| two  |
+------+
| 5    |
| 1    |
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 2    |
| 1    |
| 1    |
+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need the number of occurrences of each grade like so:

```
mysql> SELECT two, COUNT(1) as count  from data lookup where date >= '2018-10-23 00:00:00' AND date < '2018-10-23 23:59:59' GROUP BY two;
+------+-------+
| two  | count |
+------+-------+
| 1    |     5 |
| 2    |     3 |
| 5    |     1 |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT I want to include grades, even if they do not exist in the selection, like:

```
+------+-------+
| two  | count |
+------+-------+
| 1    |     5 |
| 2    |     3 |
| 3    |     0 |
| 4    |     0 |
| 5    |     1 |
| 6    |     0 |
+------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've seen solutions with LEFT JOIN and lookup tables, but they are way too complex for my SQL-beginner-head to wrap around.

I have made a lookup table (noten=grades):

```
mysql> SELECT * from lookup;
+-------+
| noten |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I can't get it right...

```
mysql> SELECT two, COUNT(1) as count  FROM data LEFT JOIN lookup on two=lookup.noten  WHERE date >= '2018-10-23 00:00:
+------+-------+
| two  | count |
+------+-------+
| 1    |     5 |
| 2    |     3 |
| 5    |     1 |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your assistance would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a `left join`.  The trick is to get the `count()` and date conditions right.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT l.noten, COUNT(d.noten) as count
FROM lookup l LEFT JOIN
     data d
     ON d.noten = l.noten AND
        d.date >= '2018-10-23' AND d.date < '2018-10-24'
GROUP BY l.noten
ORDER BY l.noten;
```

In particular, notice that the date logic doesn't need time components to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, this does what I need it to do. And thanks for the hint about date logic, much nicer now. See below for the exact code that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of creating an actual lookup table, you can emulate it within the query itself using [`Union All`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), and use it as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- You will need to do a `Left Join` from this lookup table to the `data` table.
- **Note** that when using Left Join(s), any condition(s) on the right-side tables, should be specified in the `On` clause, instead of `Where`. If they are specified in `Where`, it would limit your results, and effectively make it an Inner Join only.

Try the following:

```
SELECT agl.grade, COUNT(d.two) FROM 
(SELECT 1 AS grade UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6) AS agl
LEFT JOIN data AS d ON d.two = agl.grade AND 
                  d.date >= '2018-10-23 00:00:00' AND 
                  d.date < '2018-10-23 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY agl.grade
```

Comment: I like your approach, its very concise, BUT: this throws me an error message: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS agl
LEFT JOIN data AS d ON d.two = agl.grade AND 
                  d.date >=' at line 7

Comment: @shortfish there was a typo. I fixed it. my technique has an advantage of avoiding unnecessary creation on additional lookup table

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS`  by `cross/left joins` recursively as :

```
select q.rn as two, 
       count(coalesce(t.two)) as count
  from
    (  
    select @rownum := @rownum + 1 rn
      from (select @rownum := 0) t
      cross join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS 
     limit 6 
    ) q 
  left join data t
    on ( t.two = q.rn and date >= '2018-10-23 00:00:00' and date < '2018-10-23 23:59:59' )
 group by rn    
 order by rn;

 two    count
  1       5
  2       3
  3       0
  4       0
  5       1
  6       0
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AIDVC35785)

Comment: In your demo, you don't have the "where date..." condition and it works fine. With the code you posted here, however, I get the same results as in my question. Grades that do not show up are not counted. Does the "where" condition need to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the mildly modified version by @gordon-linoff which did the trick. Thank you all!

```
SELECT lookup.noten, COUNT(data.two) as count 
FROM lookup LEFT JOIN
data ON data.two = lookup.noten AND 
data.date >= '2018-10-23' AND data.date < '2018-10-24' 
GROUP BY lookup.noten 
ORDER BY lookup.noten;
```

Comment: if you don't have your own answer no need to multiplex an already existing answer. Adding comments is enough for these cases.